# Magento 2 - Product displaying takes so much of time

Tags: product, magento2.2.4, pagespeed

[image]

Product displaying takes so much of time in Magento 2. I click on the product it takes so much time to display the product.

Comment: Check your server configuration.

Comment: ok. can you please tell me how check the server configuration

Comment: presently we are using godaddy hosting

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-to-find-the-system-configuration-and-hardware-information/

Comment: Check your cache status first: `php bin/magento cache:status`

Comment: here my problem is the product not displaying it is loading

Comment: Anything in console?

Comment: What is cache status?

Comment: cache status is disabled

Comment: That's why your page takes too much time. Please enable it and check page speed : `php bin/magento cache:enable`